# KafkaConsumer and KafkaProducer idle time configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Our applications are long running, need to run until stopped/killed. The configuration for that is to set `connections.max.idle.ms` for both Producer and Consumer which is of type `long`. Is there a way to set to infinite, don't close, or something like that?

Or, lets say if `connections.max.idle.ms` is set to 10 minutes, Producer is idle for 20 minutes because there is nothing to produce. Later Producer need to produce messages, will Producer automatically wake up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the producer will automatically recreate the channel with Kafka broker after the producer starts to send message again.

When `connections.max.idle.ms` expires, the channel will be closed by the client code to reduce the resource usage. If you want to disable this behavior you could set it to -1.